# How to customize page template using Liferay UI?

Tags: html, css, templates, liferay

Is it any ways to add html and css code to page templates using UI of lifery? Because when I'm opening `page template - > add page template` I've got smth like this[image] with this strange message

> It is not possible to specify customization settings for pages in site
>   templates or page templates.

How to write my own template with custom CSS and Pictures that I have already added to my custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is helpful. See the *Look and Feel* tab? That's where you can add custom CSS. Custom JavaScript logic can be added in the *Advanced* tab.